# Did classical Romans have preferences for slaves based on ethnicity or racial characteristics?

Tags: ancient-rome, slavery, racism

I have read of Greeks who were valued as tutors, secretaries, etc, presumably because they were literate and other races (barbarii) tended not to be.

Are there any historical records of general Roman prejudices in selection of slaves?

E.g, Britons and Germans are wild and untrainable, so send them to the mines, fields, Ludus.

Or, if not strictly ethnicity, then skin colour? I do no mean to upset anyone or be controversial, but I have read of a jet black Nubian being highly prized as a "trophy slave" (similar to the concept of a "trophy wife").

That seems like a positive prejudice - if there can be such a thing - are there others? E.g a certain race make great hunters, cooks, etc.  Nothing specialized, like gladiators, just general prejudice.

Comment: This UNVR article has a section on this: [Ethnicity and Slavery](https://www.unrv.com/slavery.php).

Comment: @TheHonRose: "Corsicans" is not a race! In all ancient Greek and Roman sources that reached us, there is no single mentioning of "race". I challenge anyone to give me a counterexample. "Race" is a much later concept.

Comment: Do you mean "untrainable" instead of "unattainable"?

Comment: @Alex The word "race" was used to mean "nationality" in the past, before its modern meaning took over.

Comment: In what sense does the questioner use it? It's not clear to me from the question.  Perhaps, given the cited examples of Britons, Germans, Greeks and Nubians, meaning something like "ethnicity"?

Comment: @Spenser: the word "race" did not exist before 16 century. Therefore it was not used.

Comment: @Mark Olson: I think trying to understand Roman attitudes in purely modern terms is going to be an exercise in futility.  If anything, it seems more cultural (that is, Romans vs barbarians) than racial or ethnic.  Simplistically, Rome conquered "barbarian" lands like Britain, "civilized" them, and eventually the people became Roman citizens.  As for picking slaves for decorative purposes, that seems much like picking actors today.

Comment: @Alex Nevertheless, you've misapplied the most recent meaning of the word in your comment that "Corsicans are not a race", because the concept behind the older meaning existed in Roman times. E.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_race_concepts): "The Roman emperor Julian factored in the constitutions, laws, capacities, and character of peoples."

Comment: @Spencer "`Do you mean "untrainable" instead of "unattainable"?`" - yes, I do. Damn the spell checker !!

Comment: There are definitely many documented "racial" or ethnic stereotypes Romans have for slaves from different origins. Epirote slaves were thought to be good shepherds, for example.

Comment: That's the sort thing that I was looking for (+1)

Comment: Would you like to work it up into an answer?